# Use ng-href to view example-detail view in an ng-repeat with a collection that have objectId

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to make an ng-repeat with a link to go to the specific view of the item clicked.

```
<a ng-href="/faq/{{faq._id}}">
  {{faq.question}}
</a>
```

This works fine with collections like

```
{
  _id: "dJ4nsqh42zJFAtSsx",
  question: "Lorem ipsum lorem Ipsum televisión?",
  answer: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}
```

with a normal `_id` but doesn't work when the document is like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("56d5f6f51b11e8001756fe52"),
  question: "Example question?",
  answer: "Example answer"
}
```

Instead of having the normal url, I get something like this:

`http://example.com/faq/%7B%22_str%22:%2256d5f6f51b11e8001756fe52%22%7D`

Which results in nothing showing up.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Do you have possibility to replace ObjectId("56d5f6f51b11e8001756fe52") with "dJ4nsqh42zJFAtSsx"? What router package do you use?

Comment: I'm using compose.io for the database, unfortunately, when I try to edit the id, it reverts back to `ObjectId...`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to insert the details directly to db, id is saved as objectid

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Angular filter (e.g. name it **navid**), maybe this will help:

```
<a ng-href="/faq/{{faq._id | navid}}">
  {{faq.question}}
</a>
```

and angular filter example:

```
angular.module('yourApp', [])
.filter('navid', function() {
  return function(id) {
      // here check if your input object is ObjectId or not and try to get
      // the id from it.

      // maybe something similar to this?
      // I assumed that you are talking about MongoDB
      if (typeof(id) === 'ObjectId') {
          return id.str;
      }    

        return '[Unknown id]';
  };
});
```